# No connection between 2 XBee modules

Tags: arduino, xbee

I have two arduinos, each coupled with an arduino wireless shield and an [xbee](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11217) on top of it.

The communication is not working as expected. I can receive and send bytes, but the connection between the modules is often interrupted, so the serial buffer is growing quite a lot.

Furthermore, if I move the modules more than 1 meter away from each other, the connection is refused completely.

I was wondering, if my xbee modules might be a kind of broken or I maybe misconfigured them.

Any ideas?

The source code of the sender:

```
void setup()
{
 Serial.begin(9600); 
}

void loop()
{
 int sensorValue = analogRead(0);
 int val = map(sensorValue, 0, 1023, 35, 160);
 Serial.write(char(val));
 delay(250);
}
```

The source code of the receiver:

```
#include <Servo.h>

Servo motor1;
Servo motor2;
Servo motor3;
Servo motor4;

void setup()
{
  motor1.attach(9);
  motor2.attach(10);
  motor3.attach(3);
  motor4.attach(11);

  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{ 
  if(Serial.available() > 0)
  {
    byte incoming = Serial.read();
    int inValue = constrain(incoming, 35, 160);
    motor1.write(inValue);
    motor2.write(inValue);
    motor3.write(inValue);
    motor4.write(inValue);
  }
  delay(250);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A few things to consider:

- Make sure the radios haven't formed a network on channel 26 (0x1A).  The XBee module has to run with lower power on that channel, so I usually set `ATSC` to 0x7FFF to exclude channel 26.
- That model of XBee uses a PCB antenna, located in the tapered part of the module.  Make sure that doesn't have anything metallic above or below it (ground plane, components, wires) and that you aren't putting it in a big metal enclosure that would limit the signal.
- Check the value of `ATRO`, the Packetization Timeout.  You'll want it set to a low value (3-5) or even 0 or 1 if you want the XBee to transmit characters as they come in, instead of waiting for more data to possibly group together in a single packet.
- If you're having range issues, check the `ATPL` (Power Level) and `ATPM` (Power Mode) settings.  Enabling Boost Mode (`ATPM=1`) and highest power level (`ATPL=4`) could help with the range issue.
- You might want to change your receive code to poll more often for bytes, or to even ignore multiple bytes and only use the last value received.  This will prevent a backlog of bytes on the receiving end.

Process any outstanding bytes:

```
while (Serial.available() > 0)
{
    byte incoming = Serial.read();
    int inValue = constrain(incoming, 35, 160);
    motor1.write(inValue);
    motor2.write(inValue);
    motor3.write(inValue);
    motor4.write(inValue);
}
```

Ignore buffered bytes and only write the last value:

```
if (Serial.available() > 0)
{
    byte incoming;
    // read all bytes but only use the last value read
    while (Serial.available() > 0) incoming = Serial.read();
    int inValue = constrain(incoming, 35, 160);
    motor1.write(inValue);
    motor2.write(inValue);
    motor3.write(inValue);
    motor4.write(inValue);
}
```

Comment: thank you for your detailed answer. I would like to build a quadrocopter. For that, I assembled an aluminium frame. There is no problem with aluminium, isn't it?
Do you think, the problem could be the wireless shield for arduino? I detected, that I can configure the xbee only through one of the two wireless shields (I didn't use a xbee explorer usb component).